# how to access hash in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am passing the hash in radio button option in my view like

> 

while selcting the radio buttons it passes the hash ( keys and values) to the database..

how can i access the the passed parameter in controller.
inorder to update the count field based on the selection .

any help on this..

Answer (score 0):

Your development.log logs the contents of `params` - you can find out where it ends up by looking there.

Answer (score 0):

For each k in your hash, you can access the passed value by:

```
params[k]
```

Keep in mind that a radio button only passes it's value if it's selected, otherwise you get nothing.